# Select text and add to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iv been using a simple html5 note taking application and would like to expand it.

**I would like to be able to select some text on a page and add that as a note .** Im not sure if I would create a new function or amend one that already exists .

I have included the code below that I think adds the item to localstorage .

I have also included a link to the github page where the html code is : https://github.com/oxhey/Notes-Manager

```
if(newItem){ // don't push when generating from localStorage
            allTitles.push(listTitle);
            allLists.push({'title': listTitle, 'note': listNote});

            localStorage.setItem('allLists',JSON.stringify(allLists));
            localStorage.setItem('allTitles',allTitles);
        }

        return listContainer;
    };
```

HTML :

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;"  role="form" id="newListForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="newListInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title<span>*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" required="true" class="form-control" name="newListTitle" id="newListInput" placeholder="List Title" onblur=' this.value=this.value.replace(/(^\s*)/g, "") ; '>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="newNoteInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Note<span>*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <textarea required class="form-control" name="newListNote" id="newListNote" placeholder="Write Note" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
                        <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am assuming `select` as in select the text using the mouse. Am I right?

Comment: Yes as is copy and paste . I have a right click menu with an option to add note so I would like to be able to select and right click to add the note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in Javascript. Use the following code:

```
if(window.getSelection){
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
}else if(document.getSelection){
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
}else if(document.selection){
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```

[Selection | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

**EDIT:**

Try using the following JS code along with your HTML:

```
function submitForm(){
  var listTitle = document.getElementById("newListInput").value;
  var listNote = document.getElementById("newListNote").value;

  console.log(listNote);


  // not sure why you have the following 2 lines
  //if(newItem){ // don't push when generating from localStorage
    //allTitles.push(listTitle);  

  var allLists = [];

    allLists.push({'title': listTitle, 'note': listNote});

    localStorage.setItem('allLists',JSON.stringify(allLists));
    localStorage.setItem('allTitles',allTitles);
//  }
}
//return listContainer;
//};
```

Comment: @Jess In my code snippet above, `selectedText` can be used as `listNote` in your code. Looks like you are having two items that you are pushing into the localStorage. Can you please post the HTML in your question as well, so I can help you better?

Comment: @Jess Please checkout the edit in my answer above. It should work along with your HTML.

Comment: The problem is that the js code is part of a much bigger js file . Im not sure where thsi would fit in.

Comment: @Jess Is it possible for you to post all of the JS code and HTML? You can delete it later if it is confidential.

Comment: I dont think stackoverflow will let me . i have posted a github link

Comment: @Jess You should really be using the first code snippet that you posted. Put it in your JS code where you want the code to execute after you have selected the text.